# Dealing with C# sdk in android

Tags: java, c#, android, dll, sdk

I'm controlling some external device using my android app, and in order to control this device it provides an sdk which is a **C#**(**.dll**) files, I know how to load .dll libraries into java and how to use it, but I can't access a lot of methods inside these libraries because it takes C# native arguments like `structs` which is not available in Java, and I tried equivalents in Java like classes with public elements to represent a `struct` but it keeps give me the error:  `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported argument type`

This is how I deal with the Library(using **jna**):

```
import outsource.classes.MyClass;

import com.sun.jna.Library;
import com.sun.jna.Native; 
public class Test {

    public interface simpleDLL extends Library {

        long H264_DVR_GetLastError(int num); // accessed without any problems

        boolean H264_DVR_SetDVRMessCallBack(MyClass obj, long num); // this "MyClass" is mainly a STRUCT in the C# sdk
    }

    static
    {
        System.loadLibrary("NetSdk");
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        simpleDLL INSTANCE = (simpleDLL) Native.loadLibrary(("NetSdk"),
                simpleDLL.class);

        System.out.println(INSTANCE.H264_DVR_GetLastError(4));
        System.out.println(INSTANCE.H264_DVR_SetDVRMessCallBack(new MyClass(),
                0));

    }

}
```

And this is how I created `MyClass.Class`:

```
public class MyClass() {
      public String Id = "myDevice";
      public String UserName = "admin";
      public int password = 1234;
}// also tried declaring the values inside a constructor but nothing changed
```

and this is how the struct defined inside the sdk:

```
typedef struct _DEVICEINFO
{
    char id[64];
    char user[64];
    int pw; 
}DEVICEINFO,*LP_DEVICEINFO;
```

p.s. I know there are some ways to write an android app with C# code using VisualBasic(e.g [vs-android](https://code.google.com/p/vs-android/)) but that won't work in my case as the app is already written and running with java and it's pretty huge with a lot of other functionalists so it can't be rewritten.

Comment: Android doesn't run C# or Windows DLLs in general. Why are you trying to integrate with a desktop(?) DLL on your mobile device?

Comment: I would like to follow this question. :)

Comment: @ElliottFrisch that's because I bought an NVR device which supposed to be controlled through my android app, this device has an sdk in order to any third party can deal with it, this sdk is in C#, and as I said I can deal with the methods of this sdk but only the methods that take arguments that I can provide using android, but methods that are using parameters like struts I can't deal with.